# MySQL trigger old and new query

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

I'm trying to create trigger so when "FirstName" row `update` in "order" table the new value will be saved in table triggers.FirstName.

I have constructed MySQL query this way, however I'm getting "You have an error in your SQL syntax;" I guess I'm doing something wrong:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER when_updated
BEFORE UPDATE 
ON order
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
INSERT INTO triggers (timestamp, FirstName) VALUES (now(), NEW.FirstName)
END$$
DELIMITER;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have not terminated the `INSERT` statement,

```
DELIMITER $$ 
CREATE TRIGGER when_updated 
BEFORE UPDATE ON `order` FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN 
    INSERT INTO triggers (timestamp, FirstName) 
    VALUES (now(), NEW.FirstName);
                              -- ^ HERE
END$$ 
DELIMITER;
```

ALSO, `ORDER` is a RESERVED KEYWORD. Delimit it with backtick so it can be used as table name.

Comment: INSERT INTO triggers (timestamp, FirstName) VALUES (now(), NEW.FirstName);
can you please tell me what else do i need to terminate?